# Pandas: concatenating conditioned on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, set, concatenation

I am concatenating two Pandas dataframes as below.

```
part1 = pd.DataFrame({'id'    :[100,200,300,400,500], 
                   'amount': np.random.randn(5)
                    })

part2 = pd.DataFrame({'id'    :[700,100,800,500,300], 
                   'amount': np.random.randn(5)
                    })

concatenated = pd.concat([part1, part2], axis=0)
     amount   id
0 -0.458653  100
1  2.172348  200
2  0.072494  300
3 -0.253939  400
4 -0.061866  500
0 -1.187505  700
1 -0.810784  100
2  0.321881  800
3 -1.935284  500
4 -1.351507  300
```

How can I limit the operation so that a row in `part2` is only included in `concatenated` if the row `id` does not already appear in `part1`? In a way, I want to treat the `id` column like a set.

Is it possible to do this during concat() or is this more a post-processing step?

Desired output for this example would be:

```
concatenated_desired
     amount   id
0 -0.458653  100
1  2.172348  200
2  0.072494  300
3 -0.253939  400
4 -0.061866  500
0 -1.187505  700
2  0.321881  800
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call `drop_duplicates()` after `concat()`:

```
part1 = pd.DataFrame({'id'    :[100,200,300,400,500], 
                   'amount': np.arange(5)
                    })

part2 = pd.DataFrame({'id'    :[700,100,800,500,300], 
                   'amount': np.random.randn(5)
                    })

concatenated = pd.concat([part1, part2], axis=0)
print concatenated.drop_duplicates(cols="id")
```

Comment: I checked the [manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) but am still not quite sure. Does this ensure that I keep the first occurrence (row) of a given `id`?

Comment: Yes, there is a take_last argument: boolean, default False. Take the last observed row in a row. Defaults to the first row. So you can choose which one to keep, the first or the last.

Comment: so, `take_last = False` (default) implies `take_first`?

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the id's not in part1

```
In [28]:
diff = part2.ix[~part2['id'].isin(part1['id'])]
diff

Out[28]:
     amount   id
0 -2.184038  700
2 -0.070749  800
```

now concat

```
In [29]:
concatenated = pd.concat([part1, diff], axis=0)
concatenated

Out[29]:
     amount   id
0 -2.240625  100
1 -0.348184  200
2  0.281050  300
3  0.082460  400
4 -0.045416  500
0 -2.184038  700
2 -0.070749  800
```

You can also put this in a one liner:

```
concatenated = pd.concat([part1, part2.ix[~part2['id'].isin(part1['id'])]], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get a column with an `id`, then use it as an index. Perform manipulations with a real index will make things easier. Here you can use `combine_first` that does what you are searching for:

```
part1 = part1.set_index('id')

part2 = part2.set_index('id')

part1.combine_first(p2)
Out[38]: 
       amount
id           
100  1.685685
200 -1.895151
300 -0.804097
400  0.119948
500 -0.434062
700  0.215255
800 -0.031562
```

If you really need not to get that index, reset it after:

```
part1.combine_first(p2).reset_index()
Out[39]: 
    id    amount
0  100  1.685685
1  200 -1.895151
2  300 -0.804097
3  400  0.119948
4  500 -0.434062
5  700  0.215255
6  800 -0.031562
```